# How can I add a max date with VueJs in a html input?

Tags: vue.js

I want to know how can I add a max value dynamically with vuejs to a date input.

My html is:

```
<input type="date"
    class="form-control" 
    max = "How can I get a value dynamically"
    id="exampleInputEmail1" 
    v-model="form.collection_date" 
    placeholder="Ingresa la fecha de la recaudación" 
    required>
```

I have a max attribute I wonder how can I put that value dynamically with VueJs.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the date that you want as max (Date typed).

For example, if you wanted to set today as max date, you should add

```html
<input type="date"
    class="form-control" 
    :max="new Date()"
    id="exampleInputEmail1" 
    v-model="form.collection_date" 
    placeholder="Ingresa la fecha de la recaudación" 
    required>
```

The point is to **bind** the date you want as max. Note that, in date-type input, the `max` should be a date too.

Comment: You have to format the Date from javascript default to yyyy-mm-dd like: new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]